# Image hosted as HTTPS in Tomcat does not display in Outlook

Tags: tomcat, web, https, outlook

I have a question regarding image hosting.

I have a tomcat server which hosts a website over https. It contains a number of images whose links are used in some emails. I expect the images to be displayed correctly in email in outlook.

I can access these images from browser with no problems. But in the outlook email, it always displayed as a red cross. Surprisingly, there are some people that can actually see those images but some people cannot.

I started to think whether it is a certification issue or some other security related issue.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell about outlook, but my mail client is configured to never load anything from the internet that is referenced from emails. If the clients in question usually load such images, I'd advise to check - e.g. use http instead of https (this might point to a certificate issue), use jpg instead of png, use URLs with just ASCII characters etc.

Depending on your technical knowledge, you might also want to use a network sniffer to see if there's any attempt to connect to the webserver. Also check the webserver for any logs: Are they regular access logs, are error messages logged etc.